# Motherboard ga-g33-ds3r. pwr supply

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan

I am bench testing a gigabyte ga-g33-ds3r which is giving power problems.

When the 4 pin power plug is inserted into the motherboard socket- both CPU and video card fans run but start and stop every few seconds.

When I take out the 4 pin plug - leaving the main board power connector - shorting the start switch gives both fans running evenly. Is this problem the motherboard or does this mean no power to the CPU?

Comment: This is impossible to analyse remotely. You need at least a replacement PSU to verify if that is a problem, and even with that - the MB might still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to my earlier question,ref,Motherboard GA-G33-DS3R.Power supplies / Fans etc. After more testing plus using three different power supplies, removing the board battery for 10 minutes, reducing the memory to 2gb on one slab, using the on board VGA, plus very seriously cleaning the contact side of the Intel Quad 4 CPU, using a magnifying glass, I found smudges of heat sink paste which were not readily seen by the eye and were blanking off some of the CPU underside contacts.

I finally managed to boot into the Set Up. However was disappointed to find that the whole board closed down just prior to booting in the windows. Here i solicited information from a Professional and learned something new. ( One is never to old to learn ) Was informed that the CPU was not recognising from the HDD a previously installed Windows and that I must reinstall Windows again on the HDD, which would then be booted as normal.

The answer to my two problems were,

1.Take more care with the Heat sink paste, keeping the fingers free of the stuff when handling a CPU. 
 2. Ensure a new copy of windows is installed along with any CPU change.